# Enforcing native Python3 to show up when I enter Python in CentOS 7

Tags: bash, python, path, installer-anaconda

I have installed both `native Python 3` and `Anaconda Python 3` however, at the moment, I want to use native `Python 3` when I enter `$ python`. Do you know why it defaults to Anaconda Python 3 and how can I fix it?

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/miniconda/bin:/scratch3/MATLAB/matlab/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/.local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/IT/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/bin:/scratch/sjn-p2/anaconda/anaconda2/bin:/usr/bin/python3
```

and

```
$ which -a python
alias python='python3'
    /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3
    /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3
    /usr/bin/python3
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/scratch/sjn-p2/anaconda/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python3
alias python=python3
```

I want to enter `$ python` and be able to use `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: The alias is a good start, but /usr/bin must be in the PATH **before** the anaconda directories. By the way, since PATH is a list of directories and /usr/bin/python3 is not a directory, it doesn't make sense to put /usr/bin/python3 in the PATH.

Comment: `update-alternatives` should help you